# Error with big list in a loop to build a dataframe - python

Tags: list, dataframe, loops, binance

I´ve trying to made a big dataframe with all usdt pairs from binance.
I made a list whit this information, but does not work when a I put it in a loop.
The interrogant is when I try whit a shorter list this works.

```
prices = pd.DataFrame(client.get_all_tickers())
pairs = prices.loc[:,"symbol"]
listpairs = pairs.tolist()
coins = [s for s in listpairs if "USDT" in s]

for n in coins:

   df["close"+n] = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(n, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, "11 nov, 2021"))[1]
   df["high"+n] = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(n, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, "11 nov, 2021"))[3]
   df["low"+n] = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(n, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, "11 nov, 2021"))[4]
   df["volume"+n] = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(n, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, "11 nov, 2021"))[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Binance limits API request to a weight of 1200 per minute.
The weight of the request differs check the Binance API docs e.g. pinging the server has a weight of 1.

You can either add a sleep timer so when the weight hits 1200 it pauses the loop for a minute. Or you can use the websocket (probably better).